# How to fix flickering of objects and figures in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Here I, have am tying to simply make 2 rectangles using pygame module. I have made them using 2 methods but they don't seem to work. Please suggest some that could work.
(I am using Python 3.8.3)

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))

box_color = (255, 0, 0)
color = (0, 150, 100)

ybox = 20
xbox = 20

running = True
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                                             
        ybox += 5


    if (ybox >= 45):
        ybox = 45                                                               
pygame.draw.rect(screen, box_color, pygame.Rect(xbox, ybox, 50, 50), 2)
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.draw.rect(screen, box_color, pygame.Rect(20, 95, 50, 50), 2)
pygame.display.flip()

screen.fill(color)
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your game is flickering because of the multiple calls of `pygame.display.flip()` and `pygame.display.update()`. One update of the display at the end of the application loop is sufficient. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering.

Remove all calls of `pygame.display.update()` and `pygame.display.flip()` from your code, but call it once at the end of the application loop. However, clear the display before drawing the objects:

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            ybox += 5
        if (ybox >= 45):
            ybox = 45                                                               

    # clear disaply
    screen.fill(color)

    # draw objects
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, box_color, pygame.Rect(xbox, ybox, 50, 50), 2)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, box_color, pygame.Rect(20, 95, 50, 50), 2)

    # update dispaly
    pygame.display.update()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)